# Will a row always have same value for %%physloc%% in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I have been exploring the practical uses of the `%%physloc%%` pseudo-column as a row-identifier. Unfortunately, I have been having trouble finding official documentation on `%%physloc%%`. I need to know whether this value can ever change.

I have done a bit of testing and it seems pretty static. Even if I create a backup of my database and restore on a different server, the `%%physloc%%` of each row stays the same.

Can anyone please explain whether this is reliable and/or provide links to documentation? Much appreciated.

Comment: given it refers to a physical location, it's probably not very reliable at all. consider what happens if a db is re-partitioned, optimized, etc... record physical locations will be moved and your identifiers will no longer be valid.

Comment: Which is why %%physloc%% is undocumented (officially)!

Comment: as others have pointed out it cannot be counted on, but here is perhaps a better question for you.  What do you want to use it for?  Is there perhaps another way of doing what you want?  It is a combination of page_id, file_id, and slot_id in scrambled format.  http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/sql-server-2008-new-undocumented-physical-row-locator-function/

Comment: @Matt of course there are better ways. The problem is, sometimes we inherit poorly designed systems with primary-key-less tables.

Comment: I didn't say better :), I said different.  I guess my point is seeing it is primary-key-less tables what is it that you need/want the key for is a it a temporary on the fly operation or a permanent relationship with an external source?  Because there are options available to you.  Change Data Tracking & Change vs change tracking, row_number(),  Still not a great as just adding an identity column onto the table but that can work....  Sounds like you might have explored some of those already and just looking for what could be a work around which is what brought me to %%physloc%% originally too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can change for any reason that moves rows: Rebuilds, shrink, page splits, reorganize, etc.

SQL Server does not provide a row ID.