# MsSql Get order of insertion

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-order-by

If i run a select query on a MS Sql database, without Order by clause, will it return the order of insertion?

I need to be sure that a specific row in my database has been inserted prior to another. By running a select all without any order by, this statement above would be true. I am not sure tough that the order of the rows returned is in fact the order in that they have been added to the database. All tests I made point in that direction and seem to confirm this assumption, but I was not able to find a official statement or confirmation of this anywhere.

Comment: No, data in tables is unordered. If you omit an `ORDER BY` clause then the data engine is free to return the data in what ever arbitrary order it wants, and that order can be different **every time** you run said `SELECT` statement.

Comment: "I need to be sure that a specific row in my database has been inserted prior to another"
I am wondering why?  Care to explain?

Comment: If you need to ensure you toe able to return data in the order it was inserted, then I suggest looking into an `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE` and/or adding a column that defaults to the current date and time when the row is created.

Comment: @GrahamH We have two databases and one is copied to the other regularly. The client is arguing that the one specific row arrived one day later. and I need to prove that it arrived intime.

Comment: @Larnu, thank you unfortunately that is not possible for me. I have an identity column, but that column is generated on another database and then synched. so the "generation time" is relative to the first database, not the second one. I alreay found a solution and postet it below. it worked like a charm.

Comment: Then I would suggest you add a column that stores the date and time as well as the `IDENTITY`/`SEQUENCE` solution, @sharkyenergy . Then you can easily determine what rows were inserted first; as you know *exactly* when they were.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the sugestion, will add it for sure to the next project. in this particular situation I need to find the order of an already existing dataset. this database is controlled by us, thus I can say for sure that only select and insert statements have been run within the last couple of days.

Comment: As a proposed alternative to a date/time column, simulate a rowversion column with something like `alter table dbo.foo ADD iv BINARY(8) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_iv DEFAULT @@DBTS`. I say "simulate" because a normal rowversion column will change on updates as well where this one is only stamped on inserts.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using this:

```
select mycolumns, %%physloc%% as pl from mytable order by pl desc
```

Rows that have been written one after the other will have very similar values in this column, unless it has been written something totally different. In my case it solved the problem.

Comment: You know the value of `%%physloc%%` can change, right? The position of the row in the database file(s) can change due to several reasons: see [Will a row always have same value for %%physloc%% in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005185/will-a-row-always-have-same-value-for-physloc-in-sql-server).

Comment: For example, looks what happens when I add a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on a column that isn't the `IDENTITY`: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=19db23f67476b2a4f5ac9ea684518f83)

Comment: Yes I know it can change. but in this case I am confident that for my specific situation it returns the value I need. Thank you